how to fix `"Series[Any]" not callable [operator]` mypy error
For the code below
import pandas as pd

df_data = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"a": 2, "b": 1},
        {"a": 2, "b": 10},
        {"a": 3, "b": 77},
    ]
)


df_data.groupby("a").size().to_frame("size")

mypy complains
toy.py:12: error: "Series[Any]" not callable  [operator]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

I know the complain is due to to_frame call, not sure why or how to fix?
versions:

pandas: 2.2.2
pandas-stub: 2.2.2.240807
mypy: 1.11.2
python: 3.12.4


size is not a function, get rid of () after it.

size after groupby is a method: <bound method GroupBy.size of <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7f9062802150>>

@Barmar, are you referring to pandas.DataFrame.size, which is not a function?

Also pandas.Series.size

This error is only from mypy, not when you run the script? Sounds like a problem with the type annotations of the pandas methods, not a problem with your script.

Yes, that's what my question is about and I've tagged it with mypy

I can reproduce this. Mypy reports an error, but python just runs fine. Voted to reopen

Sounds like a bug in pandas-stubs.  I did a quick search in their repo and found this issue that includes this exact error message in the title: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs/issues/886 (it's a dupe of another issue that is still open -- you could go try to agitate for someone to fix it, although it looks like there's already been an attempt: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs/pull/653)
